# Image files corrupted after deployment on nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, github, digital-ocean

I do not know why this happened. I first pushed my project to github and then git cloned it into my server(digital ocean). On my local machine i have uploaded over 350 images, but after deployment they all seem corrupt. If i remove the corrupt image and upload another one, it works ok. What actually went wrong? Is there a fix to this or i have to re upload everything again.

Comment: Are the images in your git working directory correct? Is there any difference with the repository (`git diff <filename>`)? Git uses `SHA-1` as a checksum for the files in the repository. It is unlikely even a bit changed between your computer and github.

Comment: Yeah, i am not sure it is a github issue...probably the images have some kind of localhost link in them or something...

Comment: So, these are virtual machine images? Depending on the extension git might treat them as text and do line ending substitution.

Comment: I am thinking of deleting the uploads folder and using filezilla to upload the one i have on localhost. Do not know if that is going to work